# Merge and order Lists

Tags: java, collections, arraylist

For any two ascending sorted `ArrayList<Integer>` such as

```
List<Integer> l1 = new ArrayList<Integer>();
l1.add(1);
l1.add(2);
l1.add(5);
l1.add(10);
```

and

```
List<Integer> l2 = new ArrayList<Integer>();
l2.add(1);
l2.add(3);
l2.add(5);
l2.add(11);
```

how to merge them into an `ArrayList<Integer>` whose values are

```
1,1,2,3,5,5,10,11
```

**Update**

Realised that `Integer` oversimplifies the problem; in fact these are lists of class

```
public class Tuple {
  public boolean isComment;
  public int location;
  public String text;

  public Tuple(boolean isAComment, int aLocation, String aText) {
    isComment = isAComment;
    location = aLocation;
    text = aText;
  }
}
```

As suggested, a valid solution requires a sorting, where location is first criterion, whether it is a comment is the second criterion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you implementing merge-sort?

The "bycicle"-way (`O(n)`):

```
public List<Integer> merge (List<Integer> l1, List<Integer> l2) {
    List<Integer> result = new ArrayList<>();
    int i1 = 0, i2 = 0;
    while (i1 < l1.size() && i2 < l2.size())
        if (l1.get(i1) < l2.get(i2))
            result.add (l1.get(i1++));
        else
            result.add (l2.get(i2++));
    while (i1 < l1.size())
        result.add (l1.get(i1++));
    while (i2 < l2.size())
        result.add (l2.get(i2++));
    return result;
}
```

In case of `List<Tuples>` that wouldn't change much, just make your `Tuple` `Comparable`:

```
public class Tuple implement Comparable <Tuple> {
    public boolean isComment;
    public int location;
    public String text;

    public Tuple(boolean isAComment, int aLocation, String aText) {
        isComment = isAComment;
        location = aLocation;
        text = aText;
    }

    public int compareTo (Tuple that) {
        if (location == that.location)
            return Boolean.compare (isComment, that.isComment);
        else
            return Integer.compare (location, that.location);
    }
```

}

Then, instead of using `<` operator, you should use `l1.get(i1).compareTo(l2.get(i2)) < 0`

Answer (score 4):

This answer does not contain code, you'll have to figure it out for yourself.

1. Add the `List`s to one another using `addAll`.
2. Sort the `List`s using `Collections.sort`

Comment: This would be `O(n log n)`, while `O(n)` solution is possible.